# Kicked out of session - Flashing screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, permissions, users, crash

As soon as I log in my user session, my mouse cursor flickers and kicks me out. Only a guest session seems to hold. In the login menu, I can't even select a "shutdown" option.

On a sidenote, accessing my windows loader from the GRUB2 screen sometimes gives me colorful diagonal lines on a black screen, forcing me to restart. (I am using Plop on Windows MBR)

Is there a way to troubleshoot this from a Recovery Mode or LiveCD?

**UPDATE :** After creating a new user session, I figured out that some programs wouldn't launch, or functionalities from Ubuntu would result in a Unity error.

I have also reinstalled Ubuntu on a new partition, but can't activate my copied home directory. I only see my old Ubuntu partition from my new Ubuntu partition not the other way around. Is there a way to retrieve my old Ubuntu user session and add it as a session in my new Ubuntu?

I need to recover my session for work, I have an rvm, gems, git projects and a lot environment options I would like to avoid reinstalling :(

Comment: try to access a tty `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` and add a new user `sudo useradd -m newuser` and `sudo passwd newuser`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @LittleByBlue. 
When I enter `sudo useradd -m newuser` I get `sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin 'sudoers_policy' /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only writable by owner`. 
I presume I have this because I defined my user to `user ALL=(ALL) ALL` using `visudo`. So instead I type `useradd -m newuser` and I get `useradd: Permission denied cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later` either using TTY or root console in rescue mode.

Comment: you bricked the system. you may need to dive really deep inside to fix this or just reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: Hi @LittleByBlue, I have managed to create a new session. When I log onto it, I can't activate my Wifi, and going in the "System Config" (the Ubuntu gui for the config panel), the window crashes and sends an Ubuntu error report. The report reads a Unity error. Is there any way to fix this?

On the other hand,I have installed Ubuntu over on a new partition. From this new partition, I would like to get my old Ubuntu user session. I've been following tutorials explaining how to do so from OldUbuntu->NewUbuntu but not the other way around.How to active the user home folder copied in my new Ubuntu?

Comment: just copy it `rsync -rlptgoDXvxzH --numeric-ids [--exclude={"*.iso"} ]/mnt/home/<you>/* /home/<you>`

Comment: you cannot copy a session. you can only copy the home directory with your data. as I said above your system is _bricked_. this means that it is as usefull as a _brick_. you will need to remove it.

Comment: Sorry for the term, I just meant home directory. Thanks for the help! I've settled on creating a new session on a new Ubuntu after all, but will try to copy the home directory properly. After copying and creating a new user with ssh can I make his home point to the copied home? I won't mess with root access anymore without knowing what I'm doing...